How could I get an infinite loop of some video streams with gstreamer and haskell?
I am following the tutorial from https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/blob/master/examples/advanced/GstHelloWorld.hs , I'm trying to modify it so that I can have Gstreamer play some video files on loop. Like, say I have 4 videos and I want Gstreamer to play them in sequence and once the last video ends it actually starts the first one again. The "switch" of the source location should happen every 12 seconds per video.
This is the snippet of the code that should do the loop:
  putStrLn $ "Now playing: " ++ filename
  void $ Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StatePlaying

  --let putStr2 :: [String] -> IO [()]
  let putStr2 :: Gst.ClockCallback
      putStr2 =
        traverse go . cycle  where
          go path = do clock <- Gst.pipelineGetPipelineClock pipeline
                       start <- Gst.clockGetTime clock
                       after12Second <- Gst.clockNewSingleShotId clock (start + 12000000000)
                       print "Switch!"
                       Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StateReady
                       setObjectPropertyString source "location" ( Just path)
                       Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StatePlaying
                       Gst.clockIdWaitAsync after12Second (putStr2 ["D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-2-DV-PAL.avi", "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-3-DV-PAL.avi", "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-4-DV-PAL.avi", "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-1-DV-PAL.avi"])
                   --return True

I got the idea for the loop from this piece of code
putStr2 :: [String] -> IO [()]
putStr2  = traverse go . cycle  where
    go path = do putStr path
                 putChar '\n'
                 threadDelay 1000000

I am trying to have the video file paths loop like here in ghci
ghci> :{
ghci| putStr2 :: [String] -> IO [()]
ghci| putStr2  = traverse go . cycle  where
ghci|     go path = do putStr path
ghci|                  putChar '\n'
ghci|                  threadDelay 1000000
ghci| :}
ghci> :{
ghci| putStr2 ["D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-1-DV-PAL.avi",
ghci|          "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-2-DV-PAL.avi",
ghci|          "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-3-DV-PAL.avi",
ghci|          "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-4-DV-PAL.avi",
ghci|          "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-5-DV-PAL.avi",
ghci|          "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-6-DV-PAL.avi",
ghci|          "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-7-DV-PAL.avi",
ghci|          "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-8-DV-PAL.avi"
ghci|         ]
ghci| :}
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-1-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-2-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-3-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-4-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-5-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-6-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-7-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-8-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-1-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-2-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-3-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-4-DV-PAL.avi
D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/0-12-5-DV-PAL.avi
Interrupted.
ghci>

My problem is that I am currently getting this compilation error:
[1 of 2] Compiling Main [Source file changed]

D:\stack-projects\gtk-intro-twelve\app\Main.hs:152:9: error: [GHC-83865]
    * Couldn't match type: IO [Gst.ClockReturn]
                     with: GHC.Word.Word64 -> GHC.Ptr.Ptr () -> IO Bool
      Expected: [Data.Text.Internal.Text]
                -> GHC.Word.Word64 -> GHC.Ptr.Ptr () -> IO Bool
        Actual: [Data.Text.Internal.Text] -> IO [Gst.ClockReturn]
    * In the first argument of `(.)', namely `traverse go'
      In the expression: traverse go . cycle
      In an equation for `putStr2':
          putStr2
            = traverse go . cycle
            where
                go path
                  = do clock <- Gst.pipelineGetPipelineClock pipeline
                       ....
    |
152 |         traverse go . cycle  where
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^

D:\stack-projects\gtk-intro-twelve\app\Main.hs:152:23: error: [GHC-83865]
    * Couldn't match type `[Data.Text.Internal.Text]' with `Gst.Clock'
      Expected: Gst.Clock -> [Data.Text.Internal.Text]
        Actual: [Data.Text.Internal.Text] -> [Data.Text.Internal.Text]
    * In the second argument of `(.)', namely `cycle'
      In the expression: traverse go . cycle
      In an equation for `putStr2':
          putStr2
            = traverse go . cycle
            where
                go path
                  = do clock <- Gst.pipelineGetPipelineClock pipeline
                       ....
    |
152 |         traverse go . cycle  where
    |                       ^^^^^

I'm obviously approaching this in the wrong way, I apologies early on for any broad mistakes that you see, I am still very much a novice to both haskell and gstreamer. I'm trying to recursively call on the putStr2 function within itself, but the type of Gst.clockIdWaitAsync enters in conflict with the type of let putStr2 :: Gst.ClockCallback.
I use stack exec gtk-intro-twelve-exe -- 0-12-1-DV-PAL.avi to start the application.
How should I do this? If you know a better way to loop these videos please let me know. Thank you in advance.

The question reads like "teach me Haskell". There are many textbooks available for learning Haskell. This website is for asking well thought-out questions on a specific point you're struggling with. It looks like you blindly copied code from a previous answer into something of a different type, so it's unclear why you'd expect it to work. The compiler tells you exactly what is wrong.

In hasting and trying to finish this on a tight deadline I think I didn't realize. It is much more clear know, thank you for your feedback, I appreciate it a lot. I guess it's back to studying for me!

I found a solution:
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLabels  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

-- This is a translation of the Hello World gstreamer example to haskell
-- Original C source:
-- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html
-- Written by Jaro Reinders on 2017-01-09
--
-- All comments are copied from the source C code

import qualified GI.GLib as GLib
import qualified GI.Gst  as Gst

import Data.GI.Base.Properties (setObjectPropertyInt32, setObjectPropertyString)

import Control.Monad (void, when, forever)
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Environment
import System.IO (stderr)
import System.Exit (exitFailure)
import Data.Text (pack, unpack)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

busCall :: GLib.MainLoop -> Gst.Bus -> Gst.Message -> IO Bool
busCall loop _bus message = do
  messageTypes <- Gst.getMessageType message

  when (Gst.MessageTypeEos `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    putStrLn "End of stream"
    GLib.mainLoopQuit loop
    
  when (Gst.MessageTypeNewClock `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    putStrLn "New Clock"
    --(gerror,_debug) <- Gst.messageParseError message
    --T.hPutStrLn stderr . ("Error: " <>) =<< Gst.gerrorMessage gerror
    --GLib.mainLoopQuit loop

  when (Gst.MessageTypeClockLost `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    putStrLn "Clock Lost"

  when (Gst.MessageTypeError `elem` messageTypes) $ do
    (gerror,_debug) <- Gst.messageParseError message
    T.hPutStrLn stderr . ("Error: " <>) =<< Gst.gerrorMessage gerror
    GLib.mainLoopQuit loop

  return True

onPadAdded :: Gst.Element -> Gst.Pad -> IO ()
onPadAdded queuer pad = do
  -- We can now link this pad with the vorbis-decoder sink pad
  putStrLn "Dynamic pad created, linking demuxer/decoder"
  Just sinkPad <- Gst.elementGetStaticPad queuer "sink"
  void $ Gst.padLink pad sinkPad

main :: IO ()
main = do
  progName <- getProgName
  args <- getArgs

  -- Initialization
  void $ Gst.init Nothing

  --pipeline <- Gst.parseLaunch "filesrc name=my_filesrc ! mad ! osssink"
  --print pipeline

  loop <- GLib.mainLoopNew Nothing False

  -- Check input arguments
  when (length args /= 1) $ do
    T.hPutStrLn stderr $ "Usage: " <> pack progName <> " <video filename>"
    --exitFailure
  --let arg = head args

  --let methodname = last args

  -- Create gstreamer elements
  pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just "video-player")

  let makeElement factoryname name =
        fromMaybe (error $ unpack $ "Could not create " <> name)
        <$> Gst.elementFactoryMake factoryname (Just name)

  source  <- makeElement  "filesrc"       "filesrc"
  --demuxer <- makeElement  "qtdemux"       "qt-demuxer"
  decoder <- makeElement  "decodebin"     "decoder"
  queuer  <- makeElement  "queue"         "queuer"
  conv    <- makeElement  "videoconvert"  "converter"
  alpha   <- makeElement  "alpha"         "transparency"
  sink    <- makeElement  "d3dvideosink"  "video-output"
  

  -- Set up the pipeline

  -- we set the input filename to the source element
  --setObjectPropertyString source "location" (Just $ pack arg)
  setObjectPropertyInt32 alpha "method" 2

  --caps <- Gst.capsNewAny
  
  -- we add a message handler
  bus <- Gst.pipelineGetBus pipeline
  busWatchId <- Gst.busAddWatch bus GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT (busCall loop)

  -- we add all elements into the pipeline
  -- file-source | decoder | converter | alsa-output
  mapM_ (Gst.binAdd pipeline) [source, decoder, queuer, conv, alpha, sink]

  -- we link the elements together
  -- file-source -> ogg-demuxer ~> vorbis-decoder -> converter -> alsa-output
  void $ Gst.elementLink source decoder
  --void $ Gst.elementLink conv sink

  let elementLinkMany (a:b:cs) = (&&) <$> Gst.elementLink a b <*> elementLinkMany (b:cs)
      elementLinkMany _ = return True

  void $ elementLinkMany [queuer, alpha, conv, sink]

  --void $ Gst.elementLink conv sink

  void $ Gst.onElementPadAdded decoder (onPadAdded queuer)

  {- note that the demuxer will be linked to the decoder dynamically.
     The reason is that Ogg may contain various streams (for example
     audio and video). The source pad(s) will be created at run time,
     by the demuxer when it detects the amount and nature of streams.
     Therefore we connect a callback function which will be executed
     when the "pad-added" is emitted.-}
    
  --clock <- Gst.pipelineGetPipelineClock pipeline
  --start <- Gst.clockGetTime clock
  --after12Second <- Gst.clockNewSingleShotId clock (start + 12000000000)
  
  let switch :: [String] -> IO ()
      switch []     = pure ()
      switch (x:xs) = do
         --let switchLocation :: Gst.ClockCallback
         let switchLocation = do
               print "Switch2!"
               Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StateReady
               setObjectPropertyString source "location" ( Just (pack x))
               Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StatePlaying
               return True
         threadDelay 12000000    
         switchLocation
         switch xs

  forever (switch ["D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-1-DV-PAL.avi",
                   "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-2-DV-PAL.avi",
                   "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-3-DV-PAL.avi",
                   "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-4-DV-PAL.avi",
                   "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-5-DV-PAL.avi",
                   "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-6-DV-PAL.avi",
                   "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-7-DV-PAL.avi",
                   "D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/app/new/0-12-8-DV-PAL.avi"])

  #run loop
  
  -- Out of the main loop, clean up nicely
  putStrLn "Returned, stopping playback"
  void $ Gst.elementSetState pipeline Gst.StateNull

  putStrLn "Deleting pipeline"
  void $ GLib.sourceRemove busWatchId

The switch function is the one that does the looping along with forever put in front of it.
It's still very choppy and flawed but I think I can clean it up nicely in the coming days. If you have any tips on how to further improve this please let me know in the comments.
I guess sometimes all you need is a little push from the right kind of people!

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
